# Identify vrf within packet capture

Tags: ip, vrf, capture

I have a scenario where i am capturing data where mutiple customers vrfs traverse

I am looking at my capture and ofcourse i see source & destination

However, these addresses could come from mutiple customers

e.g. 10.10.10.0/24 could belong to customer A or customer B

When capturing raw data from a link, is it even possible to find a vrf value, or a route-target ?

I know i can see route-targets / distingushers within BGP updates, but that not what i am looking for

Any ideas welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When capturing raw data from a link, is it even possible to find a vrf value, or a route-target ?

A VRF is meaningful only to a router, so once the data leaves the router the question becomes meaningless.

Route targets are attributes of routing information, not data.  MPLS packets don’t contain that information.

You can capture the MPLS labels and determine which VPN the packet belongs to.

Comment: Thanks, agreed, the MPLS label was/is the only unique attribute that was within the capture that could be used to identify the VPN.